# Run Eclipse with M2 Maven build ignores "Store method parameter names" definition

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

My application uses reflection in order to extract parameters names for a specific method.

I need the names like they are written in my code (and not arg0, arg1...).

In order to achieve this I go to: 
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler - and mark: "Store method parameter names".

(I use JDK1.8 with Eclipse Kepler)

Now, when I do something like:

```
method.getParameters()[0].getName()
```

If I run my application with Debug Configuration = Java application --> it works fine!

*BUT*, if I run it with Debug Configuration = M2 Maven Build --> it doesn't work! it show the synthesize names (arg0, arg1...)

I need it to work via Maven Build, Any idea??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to explicitly tell compiler that you want method parameter names to be preserved:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      <compilerArgument>-g:vars</compilerArgument>
      <testCompilerArgument>-g:vars</testCompilerArgument>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: OOOPPSS, I was happy to early...

I tried it for the first time and it worked, and when I tried again it didn't!!  VERY VERY STRANGE!

Comment: Found the solution:

    <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>
    <testCompilerArgument>-parameters</testCompilerArgument>

Comment: thanks for sharing it, I totally forgot that there's a separate param string for tests

Comment: Did you add this in the parent or in the child poms? You wouldn't happen to still have a working solution would you?