# Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection) in intellij 13

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

Does anyone know of an equivalent for Eclipse 4.4's Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection) compiler property in Intellij Idea 13 (or older, but I doubt it would be available)?

Edit:
This link shows how to do it with maven, but I would still like to know how it's done in Idea
[Run Eclipse with M2 Maven build ignores "Store method parameter names" definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056377/run-eclipse-with-m2-maven-build-ignores-store-method-parameter-names-definitio)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Go to edit Settings (Projects setting actually) <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Search for Java Compiler
- Add the "-parameters" option in the compiler window. 
  This should do the trick
  **NOTE**: I tried it with JDK 8 version 1.8.0 and it DIDN'T WORK. JDK 8 version 1.8.0_05 works.
  [image]
  See also
- [Enhancements to the Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/enhancements.html)
- [Constructor/Method Parameters Metadata Available Via Reflection in
  JDK 8](http://java.dzone.com/articles/constructormethod-parameters)
- [Parameter name reflection](http://www.software-architect.net/articles/new-features-in-java-8/parameter-name-reflection.html)

Try this to validate. I have copied it from the article.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

import static java.lang.System.out;

/**
 * Uses JDK 8 Parameter class to demonstrate metadata related to the parameters
 * of the methods and constructors of the provided class (includes private,
 * protected, and public methods, but does not include methods inherited from
 * parent classes; those classes should be individually submitted).
 *
 * @author Dustin
 */
public class Main {
    private static void displayParametersMetadata(final String className) {
        try {
            final Class clazz = Class.forName(className);

            // Get all class's declared methods (does not get inherited methods)
            final Method[] declaredMethods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (final Method method : declaredMethods) {
                writeHeader(
                        "Method " + method.toGenericString()
                                + " has " + method.getParameterCount() + " Parameters:");
                int parameterCount = 0;
                final Parameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();
                for (final Parameter parameter : parameters) {
                    out.println(
                            "\targ" + parameterCount++ + ": "
                                    + (parameter.isNamePresent() ? parameter.getName() : "Parameter Name not provided,")
                                    + (isParameterFinal(parameter) ? " IS " : " is NOT ")
                                    + "final, type " + parameter.getType().getCanonicalName()
                                    + ", and parameterized type of " + parameter.getParameterizedType()
                                    + " and " + (parameter.isVarArgs() ? "IS " : "is NOT ")
                                    + "variable.");
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfEx) {
            out.println("Unable to find class " + className);
        }
    }

    private static void writeHeader(final String headerText) {
        out.println("\n==========================================================");
        out.println("= " + headerText);
        out.println("==========================================================");
    }

    /**
     * Indicate whether provided Parameter is final.
     *
     * @param parameter Parameter to be tested for 'final' modifier.
     * @return {@code true} if provided Parameter is 'final'.
     */
    private static boolean isParameterFinal(final Parameter parameter) {
        return Modifier.isFinal(parameter.getModifiers());
    }

    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        displayParametersMetadata("TestProperties");
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: zpontikas
 * Date: 7/10/2014
 * Time: 17:02
 */
public class TestProperties {

    public String getSomeStringValue(String thisIsAProperty) {
        return thisIsAProperty;
    }

    public static List<Integer> getSomeLists(final List<Integer> anotherProName) {
        return anotherProName;
    }

    public void manyProperties(final String onePropertyString,final int anotherIntProperty, final boolean thisIsBool) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -g:vars

Comment: U r right. give me a second and I will correct this

Comment: This should work now. The **-parameters** option needs to be added in compile time so that the parameter names are added in the compiled code

Comment: It still doesn't work for me - using this setting I get the same as without it - arg0 instead of parameter name. With this+ your previous solution, the result is the same as before: error. I will try to improvise

Comment: Hi there. I was using Java 8 update 1 and it didnt work. When I updated to the last one (5 atm) it worked

Comment: I am using java 1.8.0_05

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57095/discussion-between-zpontikas-and-near-ethic).

Comment: Thank you for your effort. The problem was actually with the particular project I was working on. I started it from scratch and it worked without any trouble so I went back to investigate - it had a run configuration still running (a server that was left running). Once I stopped the server, everything worked perfectly, so Thank you very much for this. It was driving me crazy.